# Highcharts error when add and shift data to hidden series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So there seems to be an error when dynamically adding data to a hidden series in Highcharts.

Say I have two series on a chart that both update on the same interval of time. Say also that I'd like to ensure that neither of the two series have more than a certain number of points, therefore leading me to use the optional `shift` boolean during a `series.addPoint()` operation.

The problem I run into is that, if one of the series is toggled and made invisible for some time, when re-toggling that series, much of the data that should've been shifted is still present.

I've made an example fiddle of this (just toggle `data1` in the chart legend for a few seconds and then re-toggle)

http://jsfiddle.net/mmuelle4/c00cLfs5/ (change `funcToTest` to see how various fixes don't quite give the "shift" look)

I'm using the latest version at the time of this post (Highcharts JS v4.0.4).

I think what I've uncovered is still an error that will need to be addressed by Highcharts, but I figured I'd ask the question - is there a better way to perform series length checking and data adding/shifting for multiple series than in the linked fiddle that would get around this issue? I can think of some clunky ones off the top of my head, but I thought I'd come to SO for some elegance :)

Link to bug on Github (for tracking): https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3420

Comment: Related [bug](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3420) on github.

Comment: I posted it :) (unless you're talking about a different one)

Comment: It's the same, just it's good idea to keep bug report in that question too - users, once visited this question, can find out that's a bug and can monitor bug's status. ;)

Comment: Added link to the bug for tracking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can workaround this issue by managing shift on your own. Simply store in some array all points and shift them there. Then call `series.setData(array_of_points,redraw,animation)` instead of `series.addPoint(points,redraw,animation, shift)`.

In short:

- when series is hidden use `series.setData()`
- when series is visible use `series.addPoint()` with shift-param set to `true|false`

Comment: I've implemented something very similar to this for the time being, however, there is a distinct difference in the visual effect this has versus doing an actual shift (the shift looks smoother in addPoint() than setting an entirely new series of data with setData()).

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle to show the result of this.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, I guess. When series is visible use `series.addPoint()`, when is hidden use `series.setData()`. Animation doesn't matter how it looks like when series is hidden.

Comment: Ah, understood. I'll implement that in the fiddle, but that seems like a nice fix. If you'll update the answer for clarity, I'd be happy to accept!